# JAVA - CSV file formatting (2 types of lines) – I don’t know how to split the data

Tags: java, csv

i have a CSV file with 2 types of lines:

**CSV file formatting**

```
line type 1:  "user1=",data1,data2,        
line type 2:  "user2=",data3,data4,  
data5
data6
line type 1:  "user3="data6,data7
```

I am trying to insert each user (with all his data), to Array using this code:

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
  String[] users = line.split(",");
```

Type line 1 was split fine.
The problem is to split type line 2, and i don't know how to do it.

expected result

```
users [user1, data1, data2]
users [user2, data3, data4, data5, data6]
users [user3, data7, data8]
```

source (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)

Comment: What the problem? The same split-on-comma should work. Does the meaning of the placeholders change? What's difference between the format of line and line 2? Also does the remaining lines in the input be considered?

Comment: What particular problem are you running into splitting line type 2?

Comment: I believe that you must remove all '\n' and '\r' characters before to process the csv, and only remove when are between \" characters.

Comment: Every time first element of users array is user1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with split function in your code. Use trim() to remove extra space and use substring() to detect first element(i.e. "user1=" or "user2=" etc) an modify it to user1/user2 . I used same example as you provided.

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.startsWith("\"user")) {

                if (!firstElement)
                    System.out.print("]\n");

                System.out.print("users [");
                firstElement = true;

            }
            // use comma as separato
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {

                if (country[i].trim().length() != 0) {
                    if (country[i].endsWith("=\"")) {
                        country[i] = country[i].substring(0,
                                country[i].length() - 2);
                    }
                    if (firstElement) {
                        System.out.print(country[i].substring(1));

                        firstElement = false;
                    }

                    else {
                        System.out.print(", " + country[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.print("]\n");
```

Comment: Didn't work :( the code give this result users [user1, data1, data2] users [user2, data3] users [data4] users [data5] expected users [user1, data1, data2] users [user2, data3, data4, data5, data6] users [user3, data7, data8] –